# Formatting lists into columns

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, formatting

I am trying to split my columns like so:

```
ID    Username    Password    Clearance    Class
1     foo         bar         Admin        True
etc   etc         etc         etc          etc
```

using the "{0:>8}".format(*i) method

printing to the console works, and the formatting is fine, but when I pass the text through to the popup window I am using to display search results, the formatting is more like this:

```
ID    Username    Password    Clearance    Class
 1     foo    bar      Admin   False
```

here is the code:

```
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

User_List = [["foo","bar","admin","true"],["fa","lo","user","false"]]

def Main():
    Display_Text_List = [["Index","Username","Password","Clearance","Class"]]
    for Count,Sub_List in enumerate(User_List):
        ID = str(Count+1)
        Username = Sub_List[0]
        Password = Sub_List[1]
        Clearance = Sub_List[2]
        Class = Sub_List[3]
        Display_Text_List.append([ID,Username,Password,Clearance,Class])
    Display_Text = Column_Format(Display_Text_List)
    print("Display_Text :\n")
    print(Display_Text)
    Popup_Show_Info(Display_Text)

def Popup_Show_Info(text):
    showinfo("Window", text)

def Column_Format(List):
    Text = ""
    print("LIST:",List)
    for i in List:
        print("i:",i)
        Text_Extension = "{0:>8} {1:>12} {2:>12} {3:>12} {4:>10}".format(*i)
        Text += Text_Extension+"\n"
    return Text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: You've discovered the difference between fixed-width fonts (what your terminal uses) and variable-width fonts (what tkinter is using). To solve the problem just specify a fixed-width font.

Comment: How do I do this? I tried adding: font="Courier" but It threw an error

Comment: No, pick a font that is a fixed width font. [Here's some options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces). Then tell tkinter to use that font for dialogs. For example to use the "Consolas" font, add `r.option_add('*Dialog.msg.font', 'Consolas')`.

Comment: It worked, however now my window does not change it's shape to fit the text. unlike what it did before....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some options to the root. To make your example work, add this to the top:

```
import tkinter
r = tkinter.Tk()
r.option_add('*Dialog.msg.font', 'Courier') # set the font for dialog boxes
r.option_add('*Dialog.msg.wrapLength', '800') # set the max width of dialog boxes
r.withdraw() # Hide the main window
```

In your real program you should use the root window instead of "r".